# Visio: Add arrows to Tree like connector

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

**Problem:**
I am trying to add arrows to tree connectors and can't figure out how to do it.

**Troubleshooting so far:**
I have tried the functions in the ribbon as well as right click.  I was able to select the arrows, but they don't appear on the connectors.

**Different user, same problem, more details:**
**I am also having this problem with Visio 2010. This is a new document, so no settings should be altered. I have tried to add arrows to the end (and beginning) with double tree square, double tree sloped, multi-tree square, and multi-tree sloped in the Blocks (US units).

I do this: right click-->format-->line-->arrows-->End:"05"  (I change the default end arrow from 00 to any of the options)

It appears in the preview box as having an arrow at the end, however when I hit "apply" or "ok" nothing changes on the shape in the document. When I return to the document, and then repeat the same steps the "End:" has defaulted to "End:00" again.

The "line" and "round corners" option within "line" work just fine in both the preview box and in the actual document.

[image: Default]

[image: Applying Arrows with Correct Preview but no Document Change]

Comment: Which version of Visio?  Exactly which "functions" in the ribbon did you try?  Format-->Line-->Line Ends?

Comment: put a screenshot

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems like the tree connector doesn't allow users to change the arrow style. I'm using the 2019 Pro version btw